# Rewrite domain.com/sub/ to sub.domain.com on other server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I see many questions about rewriting from `sub.domain.com` to a local `domain.com/sub/` folder, but have not found any for a rewrite in the other direction.

Keep in mind `sub.domain.com` is not on the same server as `domain.com`.

When a user goes to `domain.com/sub/`, that must actually be pointing them to `sub.domain.com` without a redirect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `domain.com` enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub(/.*|)$ http://sub.domain.com$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

### UPDATE

**As per the comments if you don't want original URL to change:** This will require you to enable `mod_proxy` on `domain.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sub(/.*|)$ http://sub.domain.com$1 [L,P,NC]
```

Comment: I had wanted to know if a rewrite is possible instead of a 301 redirect so `domain.com/sub/` still is visible in the address bar while `sub.domain.com` is the displayed content

Comment: It is **possible** however you will need to enable *mod_proxy* on `domain.com` Apache.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have to look into any possible risks. Do you  have an example of what my `domain.com/sub/.htaccess` file would look like once I enable `mod_proxy`?

Comment: You're most welcome! I have provided mod_proxy based answer as well.

Comment: Works beautifully and may or may not be my final solution, but I thank you for your time and helping me learn something new today!